# React - set localstorage with axios data before continuing

Tags: reactjs, axios

am having a small challenge setting up a proper initialization for my react app.
Having some settings in localstorage, I'd want to populate them with the data coming from an axios get request, before ANYTHING else in the app happens (e.g. initialization of the rest of the constructor lines).
What happens currently is that whilst the line executes, the code continues and reads the 'old' localstorage, which is not yet updated:

```
APP.JS
...
this.readSettingsDB(false);

this.state = {
  chartTimeAggregationType: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('timeAggregationType')) // <-- This value is still old
  dataLoading: true,
  ...



readSettingsDB(refreshPage) {
    data = axios.get('/someurl').then(response => {
    localStorage.setItem('timeAggregationType': reponse.time)
    });
}
```

Comment: could you show the complete code for the component?

Comment: Where are you doing setState() to update state value chartTimeAggregationType? What makes you assume the state value will automatically update by changing the localStorage reference?

Comment: The state is changed in the constructor, as shown in the snippet. Idea being that the default value from the beginning comes from the DB. E.g. Fill localstorage with DB value -> state constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you using refreshPage? Here is how I would handle your issue.

```
readSettingsDB = async (refreshPage) => {                  // arrow function make async
    const data = await fetch('/someurl');     // use fetch
    const response = await data.json();  
    localStorage.setItem('timeAggregationType': reponse) // set storage
    });
}
```

If you want to setState first, setState comes with a callback.

```
readSettingsDB = async (refreshPage) => {                  // arrow function make async
    const data = await fetch('/someurl');     // use fetch
    const response = await data.json();  
this.setState({
timeAggregationType: reponse 
}, () => {
    localStorage.setItem('timeAggregationType': this.state.timeAggregationType) // set storage
    });
})

}
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the state property isn’t automatically updating when localStorage is updated. They expect chartTimeAggregationType to update every time localStorage is updated.

Comment: I believe that he was updating localStorage before he got the response, I most assuredly could be wrong in my assumption.

Comment: They are updating localStorage, but their code shows no setState() to update chartTimeAggregationType after they update localStorage, which most likely they are displaying in the render of the component. They aren’t updating state and so the Rendered value isn’t changing. Is my guess at least.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear enough - sorry about that. There is no additional setState in my example. The whole challenge is to set the state right in the constructor with the localStorage. I might be very mistaken, but the issuse may lie in the localStorage itself - I can log it's value correctly after my setItem method executes, but logging that value just before the constructor, still yields the old value.